Encountering 'Module not found: Can't resolve' error with '@' import alias in Next.js project
I'm facing an issue in my Next.js project where I use JavaScript, not TypeScript. Previously, I could import a component using the default import alias '@' without problems. However, at some point, I started encountering a 'Module not found: Can't resolve' error mentioning the missing module '@/components/Forms/Login. I got the same error for another nextjs project
How can I solve this error?
